# Request timed out while trying to do Google Auth in Node.js app (v 0.10.13)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, passport.js

I'm using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) to do Google authentication in my Node.js application. I'm hosting it on Heroku. The issue that I'm facing is that it's not returning to the success callback that I have specified in my nodejs code. I expect a `Succesfuly logged in` message on successful login. When I checked the Heroku logs, it shows a `request time out

Here is my Node.js code

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

var hbs = require('hbs');

var passport = require('passport')
  , GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://floating-citadel-4714.herokuapp.com/auth/google/return',
    realm: 'http://floating-citadel-4714.herokuapp.com'
    },
    function(identifier, profile, done){
        console.log('Success');
        console.log(identifier);
        console.log(profile);
            }
            ));

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html',hbs.__express);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}


app.get('/auth',function(req,resp){
    resp.sendfile('./views/auth.html');
});
app.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google'));
app.get('/auth/google/return',
        passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/success',
                          failureRedirect: '/error' }));
app.get('/success',function(req,resp){
    resp.send('Succesfuly logged in');
});
app.get('/error',function(req,resp){
    resp.send('Error Loging in');
});
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Try running it on a local machine to see if it works correctly.

Comment: not working on the local machine too.I'm able to log the profile that i'm receiving but after that browser hangs up for a long time.And the callback not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the `done` callback in the success handler:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  returnURL: 'http://floating-citadel-4714.herokuapp.com/auth/google/return',
  realm: 'http://floating-citadel-4714.herokuapp.com'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done){
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(identifier);
    console.log(profile);
    done(null, profile); // <-- important!
  }
));
```

If you don't, Passport won't know you're done and the result will be that your request will stall and (eventually) time-out.

I would suspect that the logging messages would occur though, so this might only solve part of your problem.

(PS: looking [at the documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google#configure-strategy), the OpenID-based Google authenticator that you seem to be using will only pass two arguments to the callback; confusingly, the [example code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/blob/master/examples/signon/app.js#L31) suggests that your code should work, though)

Comment: now getting an error that says Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use

Comment: @iJay ah right, that's right, because you didn't use it :) See [the example code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/blob/master/examples/signon/app.js#L59) on how to use Passport.